# Difference between EnterCriticalSection() and TryEnterCriticalSection() and InitializeCriticalSection() and InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount()

Tags: c++11, visual-c++, exception, operating-system, synchronization

As i think that `TryEnterCriticalSection`can be called only once. So i just want to know what is difference between `TryEnterCriticalSection` and `EnterCriticalSection`.

```
#include<windows.h>
CRITICAL_SECTION csOpsPrintData;

void CreateCriticalSectionAsNeccessary()
{

    InitializeCriticalSection(&csOpsPrintData);
    InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount(&csOpsPrintData,5);

    EnterCriticalSection(&csOpsPrintData);
    TryEnterCriticalSection(&csOpsPrintData);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

> The difference is that TryEnterCriticalSection returns immediately,
>   regardless of whether it obtained ownership of the critical section,
>   while EnterCriticalSection blocks until the thread can take ownership
>   of the critical section.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682608(v=vs.85).aspx), Bing is your friend.

`TryEnterCriticalSection` also returns a value (whereas `EnterCriticalSection` doesn't) , nonzero if the call was successful and thus the ownership has been claimed by the thread. Zero if this is not the case.